# Passing variables to a URL in Python

Tags: python, url

I am struggling with passing variables to a URL I would like to open via python script.
The code works when I do not pass variables to the URL and then stops working when I do.

```
locations = (53.347633,-6.259439)

key = "sample"

webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations="+locations+"&key="+key+')
```

Could anyone show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
In [33]: locations = (53.347633,-6.259439)
In [34]: key = "sample"
In [35]: url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations={}&key={}".format(locations, key)
In [36]: url
Out[36]: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=(53.347633, -6.259439)&key=sample'
```